# how to scale a div to 0.5 and than to 1 using css animation?

Tags: css, transform, css-transitions, css-animations

I'm trying to implement go-out go-in effect using css animation.

I want the item to go back fast and than scale back to 1 slower.

Something like this:

```
div {

    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: green;
  border: 1px grey solid;
  position: absolute;

    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, -webkit-transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.1s, 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0, 0;
}

div:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
-webkit-transform: scale(1); 

}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

As James said, try animation CSS3.

To get what you want, try with his code and this changes:

```
@-webkit-keyframes scale {
    5% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

And add:

```
div:hover{
    -webkit-animation: scale 5s ease-out;
}
```

Here the example: http://jsfiddle.net/7Cf8C/

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to animate keyframes, your CSS needs to be:

```
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    border: 1px grey solid;
    position: absolute;
}

div:hover {
  -webkit-animation: scale 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
     -moz-animation: scale 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
       -o-animation: scale 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
          animation: scale 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
}

@keyframes scale {
    0% {}
    50% {transform: scale(0.5)}
}

@-webkit-keyframes scale {
    0% {}
    50% {-webkit-transform: scale(0.5)}
}

@-moz-keyframes scale {
    0% {}
    50% {-moz-transform: scale(0.5)}
}

@-ms-keyframes scale {
    0% {}
    50% {-ms-transform: scale(0.5)}
}

@-o-keyframes scale {
    0% {}
    50% {-o-transform: scale(0.5)}
}
```

Though, you can use the `transition` property too, but not as flexible as keyframes.

```
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    border: 1px grey solid;
    position: absolute;
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

div:hover {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
        -ms-transform: scale(0.5);
        -o-transform: scale(0.5);
        transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

You really should look up articles online that discuss CSS3 animation. There is literally thousands of them with great detail.

Don't forget you need to support all browsers by using prefixes.

These are:

`-webkit-`, `-moz-` and `-o-`. Sometimes you might need `-ms-` for IE. You **must** write animations without prefixes too. This is to support IE **and** most latest versions of browsers that no longer require the prefixed tags.

[**Here's a DEMO of what you want with Keyframes.**](http://codepen.io/JMDUK/pen/hkGec)

**[Here's a DEMO of what you want with the hover pseudo selector.](http://codepen.io/JMDUK/pen/kKagh)**

Also be aware of the support. Though, I wouldn't worry too much about it if you follow the last two versions rule (aimed at IE, **cough cough**).

[CanIUse CSS3 Animation](http://caniuse.com/css-animation)